# Searchbar cant filter JSON File Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, filter, searchbar

today i have a problem with my searchbar.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null)
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    const loadPosts = async () => {
        try {
            const post = await getAllPosts()
            setPosts(post)
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Couldn't load posts")
        }
    }
    loadPosts()
}, [])

return (
    <div>
        <input type={"text"} placeholder="Search..." onChange={event => {
            setSearchTerm(event.target.value)
        }}/>

    </div>
)
```

}

This is my Searchbar Component. In the Index file, did i gave a props with.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    const loadPosts = async () => {
        try {
            const post = await getAllPosts()
            setPosts(post)
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Couldn't load posts")
        }
    }
    loadPosts()
}, [])

return (
    <div className={styles.posts}>
        <h1>Market-place Valando</h1>
        <SearchList title={posts.filter(post => {
            if (post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase()) && searchTerm.trim() !== "") {
                return post.title
            }
        }).map(titles => {
                {
                    {titles.title}
                }
            }
        )}/>



        {
            posts.map(post => {
                return (
                    <div key={post.id} className={styles.key}>
                        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                        <Image width={1000} height={1000} src={post.image}/>
                        <p>Price: {post.price}.-</p>
                        <p>Description: {post.description}</p>
                        <Link href={`/posts/${post.id}`} passHref>
                            <a>Read more</a>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

I have a db.json file that i connected with an API File. In this Api File i made all the fetch stuff. This shouldnt be the problem. I think the problem is, that the filter doesnt work properly, with the titels.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, JavaScript `filter` does not return specific property values, but it returns the top entries of the array, a.k.a posts. So `return post.title` or `return true` will yield the same result. However, the problem in your code appears to be that you are not returning anything from the `map` function. All you need to do is to change it to the following:

```
.map(post => post.title)
```